# PHP Error Logs + Add a Session Value to the log entry

Tags: php

This is most likely a silly question so I have no issues with it being closed etc.

I'm debugging PHP error logs and it would be of great advantage if I could see the user that created the specific error.

The userid is keep in the session.

Is it possible to customize PHP error logs to include a session value for debugging?

thx

Comment: Yes. It is entirely possible to do this.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: uhm, how?

Comment: @zerkms You could set the userID as an apache variable (after sanitizing, etc, of course) like: `apache_setenv('userID', $_SESSION['user_id'])`, then you would then modify the LogFormat of the Apache Conf to include the usage of this new variable: `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b %{userID}n"` Then, the userID from the session will be appended to the end of the log line each time it's written.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: what if it's a parsing error (or any other that cannot be converted into exception)?

Comment: @zerkms it's a good point, but it can also be done as well. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is possible, I don't see why not:

```
try {
  //some code
} catch (Exception $e) {
    session_start();
    $log = 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
    $log .= 'By user = '.$_SESSION['user_id']. "\n";
    error_log($log);
}
```

To change error messages into `Exception` use this code:

```
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

/* Trigger exception */
strpos();
?>
```

[ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php)

Comment: It worth saying that you need to convert all php errors into exceptions first. And that not all errors might be converted.

Comment: @zerkms I wasn't sure if OP wanted all errors but I expanded to show how to achieve this